# Bind Both Text and Color to Listed Item

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

How to I bind a label to both a color and a text? The label is within a list which is created from a xib file. Below is my attempt to bind the color and text to the label.

I am getting an error of "'eventLabel' conflicts with a declaration in a child block".

```
    public ScheduleCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {

        this.DelayBind( () => {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ScheduleCell,  XSchEvent>();

            set.Bind(eventLabel).To(vm => vm.EventName);
            set.Bind(eventLabel)
                .For(eventLabel => eventLabel.TextColor)
                .To(vm => vm.EventType)
                .WithConversion("EventTypeToColorConverter");


            set.Apply();
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `'eventLabel' conflicts with a declaration in a child block"` is a C# error - it means you've got a variable name conflict.

Try changing:

```
            .For(eventLabel => eventLabel.TextColor)
```

to

```
            .For(eventLabel2 => eventLabel2.TextColor)
```